# How to refresh a fragment while DB values are updated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In our app we send and receive the events. That events are displayed as list view from database in fragment. if i added an new event that event should be displayed in fragment instantaneously. here i want to refresh that fragment when the event added in that DB.how to do it.

this is my code of fragment

```
   public class GroupChatFragment extends Fragment {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ViewGroup container;
        Bundle savedInstanceState;
        private Context context;
        private TextView chatTitle;
        private TextView chatPlace;
        private TextView chatDate;
        private TextView notificationCount;
        private String dateResult;
        private List<EventMO> groupEventMoList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<EventMO> eventMOs = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<EventMO> invitationMOs = new ArrayList<>();
        private EventDelegates eventDelegates = new EventDelegates();
        private Gson gson = new Gson();
        private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
        private ChatDisplayAdapter chatDisplayAdapter;
        private ListView groupEventView;
        private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        private TextView eventList;
        private MessageMO messageMO = new MessageMO();
        private ArrayAdapter<EventMO> dataAdapter = null;
        private UserMO userMO;
        private View view;



        @Override
        public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.dropdown).setVisible(true);
            super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "yes");

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.all:
                    displayEventInvitationList(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                    return true;
                case R.id.event:
                    displayEventList(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                    return true;
                case R.id.invitation:
                    displayInvitationList(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }

        }

        public View displayEventList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            userMO = dbHelper.getUserData(1);
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEvents(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    List<EventMO> groupEventList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                        groupEventList.add(eventMO);

                    }
                    return groupEventList;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventList) {
                    groupEventMoList = groupEventList;
                    chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                    groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                    groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                    groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
                }

            }.execute(null, null, null);
            return view;
        }

        public View displayInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            userMO = dbHelper.getUserData(1);
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllInvites(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    List<EventMO> groupInvitationList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                        groupInvitationList.add(eventMO);

                    }

                    return groupInvitationList;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupInvitationList) {
                    groupEventMoList = groupInvitationList;
                    chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                    groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                    groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                    groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
            return view;
        }

        public View displayEventInvitationList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            userMO = dbHelper.getUserData(1);
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEvents(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllInvites(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    List<EventMO> groupEventInvitesList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                        groupEventInvitesList.add(eventMO);

                    }
                    for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                        groupEventInvitesList.add(eventMO);

                    }

                    return groupEventInvitesList;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventInvitesList) {
                    groupEventMoList = groupEventInvitesList;
                    chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                    groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                    groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                    groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
            return view;
        }

        @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
                savedInstanceState) {
            //Here this.inflater,this.container,this.savedInstanceState variables are stored and that
            // are used in onOptionsItemSelected cases
            //without declaring this user get "cannot resolve symbol(inflater,container,savedinstancestate) error"
            // in onoptionitemselected method calls
            this.inflater = inflater;
            this.container = container;
            this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            userMO = dbHelper.getUserData(1);
            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            // Set Cancelable as False
            prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
            prgDialog.show();

            //inviation group for user
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                    eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEvents(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllInvites(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    List<EventMO> groupEventMOList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                        long eventId = eventMO.getEventId();
                        List<ChatMO> chatMOs1 = dbHelper.getGroupChatMessageForIsview(eventId);
                        Log.e("groupchat","eventMos1"+chatMOs1);
                        int count = 0;
                        for(ChatMO chatMO : chatMOs1){
                            count++;
                            Log.e("groupchatFragment","count"+count);
                            eventMO.setCount(count);
                            Log.e("groupchatFragment","eventMO"+eventMO.getCount());


                        }
                        Log.e("ouiside 2nd loop","event mo evnet id"+eventMO);
                        groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);


                    }
                    for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                        List<ChatMO> chatMOs1 = dbHelper.getGroupChatMessageForIsview(eventMO.getEventId());
                        Log.e("groupchat","eventMos1"+chatMOs1);
                        int count = 0;
                        for(ChatMO chatMO : chatMOs1){
                            count++;
                            Log.e("groupchatFragmentinvite","count"+count);
                            eventMO.setCount(count);
                            Log.e("groupchatFragmentinvite","eventMO"+eventMO.getCount());


                        }
                        Log.e("ouiside 2nd loop","invitation event mo mo evnet id"+eventMO);
                        groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);


                    }

                    return groupEventMOList;

                }

                @Override

                protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventMOList) {
                    groupEventMoList = groupEventMOList;
                    Log.i("inside on post","group event list"+groupEventMoList);
                    prgDialog.dismiss();
                    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                    groupEventView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);
                    chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                    groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                    groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                    groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                    groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
            return view;
        }

        private class ChatDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public ChatDisplayAdapter() {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return groupEventMoList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return groupEventMoList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int id) {
                // for sqllite management
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow, null);
                    convertView.setClickable(true);
                    convertView.setFocusable(true);
                    chatTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_title);
                    chatPlace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_place);
                    chatDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
                    notificationCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notification_count);
                    chatPlace.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    chatDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    chatTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    chatPlace.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getPlace());
                    Log.e("view","position"+groupEventMoList.get(position).getPlace());
                    String actualDate = groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate();
                    notificationCount.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

                    Log.e("view","position"+position);
                    Log.e("view","notification"+groupEventMoList.get(position).getCount());
                  notificationCount.setText(Integer.toString(groupEventMoList.get(position).getCount()));
                    Log.e("view","after notification position"+position);

                    try {
                        //date format changed here
                        Date formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(actualDate);
                        dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(formatDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    chatDate.setText(dateResult);
                    chatTitle.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getText());
                    final EventMO eventMO = groupEventMoList.get(position);
                    convertView.setTag(position);
                    View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_window_single);
                    v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.i("position", v.getTag().toString());
                            Intent groupAct = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
                            groupAct.putExtra("eventMo", eventMO);
                            groupAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(groupAct);

                        }

                    });
                }
                return convertView;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to refresh entire fragment you just need to update the dataset with new data and just call notifydataset function of the adpter

Comment: here if am in the fragment that should not be updated when the fragment is not executed again

Comment: Where u r getting notifications of insertion @selva peter

Comment: for every time i get the event from my database and displayed at fragment

Comment: Assuming you are inserting something to DB from a activity or a fragment on that point you can add the values to the Adapter inside the Fragment and call NotifyDataSetChanged method of adapter. you can get the instance of the fragment using getFragmentManager.findFragmentById() method

Comment: Ok . From where you are adding values to database @selva

Comment: i have adding the values from one activity called groupchat activity

Comment: cool. You will be having the the details which you are adding to the database right ? you are using the same for listing the list also . correct me if m wrong. if so you can pass the exact same value to the fragment from the activity .

Comment: where i have to use getFragmentManager.findFragmentById() method whether in activity or fragment

Comment: In Activity . on next to inserting values to the database @selvapeter